# How to delete a part of a formula within several cells of a column in one go?

Tags: google-sheets

I have following formulas in the cells of  column B in a Google spreadsheet:

```
              Column B
=if(A2 = "",,HYPERLINK("URL1","Label"))
=if(A3 = "",,HYPERLINK("URL2","Label"))
=if(A4 = "",,HYPERLINK("URL3","Label"))
=if(A5 = "",,HYPERLINK("URL4","Label"))
=if(A6 = "",,HYPERLINK("URL5","Label"))
and so on...
```

I want only **=HYPERLINK("URLN","Label")** part of the formula to remain there in all the cells, and rest part to be deleted. The column is of approx. 1,000 rows long.

Please note that though the formula used in all the cells are same, but the cell reference (A2, A3 etc.) and URL (URL1, URL2 etc.) are unique in each of the cells as evident above.

My ultimate goal is to put less burden on the overall calculations done by spreadsheet so that it runs a bit faster than now.

I have tried read and apply REGEXMATCH and REGEXREPLACE but failed to make them work at all.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No evidence, pnuts, but my observation with the passing time that the more i have been using formulas & functions in the spreadsheets, the slower the spreadsheets are becoming. So, i thought that its reverse should also be true - the lesser the number and/or complexity of formula, the faster the spreadsheet will come back to its original speed. I am aware that i may be entirely wrong in my assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the comments if you want to see what's happening as it runs. I modified this regex based upon new information from the questioner.

```
   function searchandreplace() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng=sht.getRange('B:B');
  var formulas=rng.getFormulas();
  var s='';
  for(var i=0;i<formulas.length;i++)
  {
    s+='<br />' + formulas[i][0];
    formulas[i][0]=String(formulas[i][0]).replace(/^.*?(HYPERLINK\(".+","Label"\))\)$/,'$1');
    s+='<br />' + formulas[i][0]; 
  }
  rng.setFormulas(formulas);
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Formulas');  
}
```

Comment: Hi cooper! thanks for your response! your script is removing the contents from column A, whereas what i want is - a part of the formulas in column B to be removed.

Comment: Okay just had to change column index from 0 to 1.

Comment: I tried that, but now it is just copying whatever in column B and puttting it in column A. Here is the link of a spreadsheet with some data : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oOB4__4ycIpG4ckdHTIhIjp3e_VkyI2R6MjW2VDK2Tc/edit#gid=0

Comment: Okay, it's working now.  I changed the range to 'B:B' and I had to adjust the regex because I assumed the 'URL1' was literal but you meant any url so I changed what's inside of the double quotes there to .+ and that seems to be working now.